# org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [abc]

Tags: java, web-services, javax

When I define (wss4j) in client-config.wsdl for BulkPanquery different PropartiesFiles where I have different key stores defined with different certificates, I'm able to have different certificates for sending and receiving. But when I use the same signaturePropFiles' with the same keystore. I get this message when I try to send a message:

```
Invocation failed with the following: 
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: 
[sha]
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: 
Cannot find key for alias: [sha]

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find key for alias: [sha]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:160)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.uploadBulkPan(Unknown Source)
at bulkPanService.BulkPanService_Client.main(BulkPanService_Client.java:34)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key 
for alias: [sha]
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: 
Cannot find key for alias: [sha]

at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
... 2 more 
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key 
for alias: [sha]
at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:745)
```

I have the same password for both certificates regarding Client.Proparties

My properties file:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
# Type - Valid Keystore Type. Eg - pkcs12 , jks   
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
# Keystore Password 
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=12345678
# Keystore Private Password
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password=12345678
# Keystore Alias
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=sha
# Keystore File Name
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keystore/client/data.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the last part of the stack trace.

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey
```

That indicates quite clearly that the alias that you are referring to in the Java keystore is missing a **private key**. Most likely you are referring to an alias which is a certificate with no private key.

Can you send me the certificate or a link to your code on GitHub.